# Are Chebyshev polynomials not monic for n $\geq$ 2?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Does anyone have a proof for the proposition that the Chebyshev polynomials are not monic for n $\geq$ 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tchebyshev Polynomials satisfy the recurrence relation:
$$T_0(x)=1 \\ T_1(x)=x \\T_{n+1}(x)=2xT_n-T_{n-1}.$$

So by inspection it isn't difficult to see that polynomials will always have the form,

$$T_{n+1}(x) = a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+O(x^{n-1}),$$

where $a_{n+1}$ is divisible by 2. So therefore Tchebyshev Polynomials are not monic for $n \gt 1$.